# Ignoring some test steps depending on variables

Tags: automated-testing, java, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber + Java + Selenium to UI test an application.

I'm using the same set of tests whether my application is deployed in qualification (for tests) or in production.

However, when I'm in production, I would like to stop my tests sooner (as to not save the data I just changed in my test).

So, is there a way to make a cucumber test scenario stop and exit with success even though all the steps weren't played?

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51632422/10512595) who is useful. However, I'm using JUnit 5 (not 4 like in the answer) and if I try using:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;

Assumptions.assumeTrue(HOME_PAGE.contains("qual"));
```

My test exit with an error.

I have though about using `System.exit(0);`. However, this exit *everything* without execution the `@After` of my test (so my test don't end really cleanly) **and** all the tests scenarios that were supposed to be played after are skip! (nb: I just want to skip the remaining *steps*, not *scenarios*.)

So, is there a way that I can skip some test's steps, exit the test scenario with success and happily go to the next test scenario (without having everything ending like it's the case when using "System.exit")?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that JUnit 5 and JUnit 4 aren't completely incompatible with each other. So, for now, I'm using [`Assume`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html) from JUnit 4 (along with other stuff from JUnit 5).

```java
import org.junit.Assume;

Assume.assumeTrue(HOME_PAGE.contains("ekwaqua"));
```

It's ugly, I don't like it (and I will be very grateful for another, cleaner, solution), but it's working.